# Calculation of the constant e using Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to calculate ***e*** for my assignment using threads for the least amount of time possible, given that the user will pass a variable with the amount of threads that will be used for the calculation, but I can't get my multithreading working properly to achieve some kind of result. I was told that a good method for calculation will be using the following mathematical expression: *e = sum( (3-4k^2)/((2k+1)!) )* , where *k = (0;infinity)*. But so far I got only this basic method:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static long fact(int x) {
        long p = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
            p = p * i;
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double e = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
            e = e + 1 / (double) (fact(i));
        System.out.print("e = " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I can't get my multithreading working properly"* Where do you try to do something with multithreading?

Comment: I don't think you can benefit much from multithreading in this case. Better use a dynamic programming approach to calculating those `fact()` values. Also you'll run out of digits, if you use `long` to store `x!`: `log2(49!) = 208.5...`

Comment: I did not post a source code with multithreading, because it's very bad. I only know the basics of threading like 
Thread t = new Thread(object) 
and 
t.start() ..

Comment: This is not a question about the calculation of e, this is an (open) question about how to do multithreading in java. Go read any of the many Java multithreading introductions then try your code to calculate e. Then and only then, if your results still are not good enough, come back and post your code and ask for help.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. When you push the `Ask Question` button, you really do need to ask a question that people can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Java 8 parrallel Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) it's easier and less error-prone than explcitly creating Threads.

```
import org.apache.commons.math.util.MathUtils;

...

public static double computeE(){
    return IntStream.iterate(0,k->k+1)
                    .limit(100000)
                    .mapToDouble(k->(3-4*k*k)/MathUtils.factorialDouble(2*k+1))
                    .parallel()
                    .sum();
}
```

On my machine, it uses the two cores and find e=2.718281828459045 for 10000 iterations which is a value where every digits are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the feedback, I did add a question, but somehow i deleted it before posting without noticing, for which I am sorry. Have a great day! :)